# Programatically search text in JQuery Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there any way to programatically search a JQuery Data Table using the search box?

I currently have something like this:

```
$('#calibhistory_click').tab('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#calibhistory').find('input[type="search"]').val("hi");
}, 5000);
```

This does input the text into the box however it does not search because I believe the search function only runs if it senses keyboard input via the user. Is there any way  to programatically call the search function using JS/JQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's how I initialize my table in my main.js

```
$(".dynamic-wide-table").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 530,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
        ]
    });
```

The problem is, there are MANY of these tables per page. How do I access the table I want?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the datatables [search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) function.

Example from the documentation:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

So the line you're looking for is `table.search( this.value ).draw();`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an object of the table. Just the table on the page in HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that - are you using the jquery dataTables plugin?

Comment: regular expressions?

Comment: I have a main.js file where I create my data table object. This page contains many tables on it. However I need to access only one of these tables. If I access my object from main.js how it will have any idea which table I am talking about? By the way, I use codeiginiter which creates many tables of this one object.

Comment: For example, I am trying to do this now, `$('#calibhistory').find('.dynamic-wide-table').search("hi").draw();` where `calibhistory` is the specific tab with the table I want.

Answer (score 1):

You're very nearly there, just trigger the `keyup` event after setting the `val` of the input:

```
$('#calibhistory').find('input[type="search"]').val("grail").trigger("keyup");
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lg22kfw2/).

Hope that helps.